# Wordpress website - Lost

Tags: wordpress, web-hosting

I had problems in my public_html directory in my web hosting.  I deleted the public_html then i upload the same directory again (public_html) with sames pages, files, everything the same.

When  i tried to open my website, the wordpress installer came, I lost my wordpress website and everything.

What should i do ? i have my database and my public_html, I tried to restore the database with the public_html folder, my theme is working but all the posts, contencts, plugins, widgets have been removed. It's like i just installed the theme right now :/

If i contact the hosting service, they should have done a backup for my wordpress and every file in the hosting ? or a system restore.. i don't know

Comment: recover it, what OS?

Comment: it's not on my own physical server, I rent a cpanel in a host

Comment: you don't have ssh access?

Comment: no, not really I have my own server with ssh access, but i hosted this website on a cpanel, I opened a ticket for a restore i don't care if month ago. But i need my website back, I don't know what happened. If i have my public html folder with my database .sql file, can i restore my website? i tried that but I failed, is there a specific way ?

Comment: the public html folder contains the wp includes, themes, everything and the database contains every link, I don't know why when i restore and open my website i get the theme but default with nothing :/

Comment: maybe write to your hosting company, we can't help you

Answer (score 0):

The public_html folder does not contain your database.  You need to login to **CPanel** and use the database restore tool. Ask your web host to assist if you're not sure about this. Almost everything that makes up your website is contained in the database, without it you will just have a blank theme with no pages (other than the theme default ones) and posts.

I recommend making a full site backup as well as a full database backup in future.  Speak to your host about setting this up and possibly scheduling it to happen automatically if you're not sure.